# Why is "Generate Transects along lines" invisible in data management tools (sampling) in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arctoolbox

I want to generate transects at equal intervals along a river's thalweg line. I have created point shapefile separately. I have searched on how to establish the transects at the points created and got to know that it can be done using "generate transects along lines". This tool is not available. I'm currently using ArcGIS 10.6 (licensed). Can anyone suggest me what is to be done in such a case?

Comment: Try a right click on the ArcTollbox window (not on a toolbox but on the white area) and check the "display loocked tool" setting (or any setting similar, not sure of the translation) if the tool appear after that that mean you dont have the level licence to use it. Also any reference I find about this tool are for ArcGIS Pro are you sure that this tool exist for ArcGIS 10.6 ?

Comment: Even after the checkbox is on/off, there is no change in the display of the tools. I think you are right. This option is not for ArcGIS. It is for ArcGIS Pro. Thank You ver much sir.

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS Desktop (version 10.6, for example), Generate Transects Along Lines tool requires creation of a route feature class. This is not required in ArcPro. See link below.

[How To: Create equally spaced transects perpendicular to a line feature in ArcGIS Pro](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000021605)

Here is an example showing what it requires in ArcGIS Desktop:

[How To: Create equally spaced transects perpendicular to a line feature in ArcMap](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012318)